# SSL certificate on CNAME

Tags: apache, ssl, saas

We have a SaaS web app. We have a wildcard SSL cert on the main domain: `*.webapp.com`

Customers can add a custom domain to their account, so instead of client.webapp.com they can setup a CNAME to have: `clientdomain.com`

We have some clients that want to add a SSL cert to their custom domains. Webapp already runs `https://client.webapp.com` but they want `https://clientdomain.com`

We are using apache (via Plesk) on the main server.

Is it possible to achieve this?